# fail() not exposed in nose for python?

Tags: python, nose

I'm using nose to run my tests and I have a test method that doesn't extend a unittest.TestCase.

I want to fail the test based on a condition but it looks like nose doesn't have a fail() method?

Actually I'm not really sure how assert_equals works either it's not defined in the tools module but somehow it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can fail the test by using built-in [assert](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) statement, which kinda looks like this under the covers:

```
   assert condition, "This condition failed"

   # which is the same as:
   if not condition: 
       raise AssertionError
```